# Turn cell references in Excel hyperlinks into the text in the referenced cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, spreadsheet

I have a column of bare URLs in Excel. Say it's Column A. I want to replace each URL with a friendly text link, like "here." Suppose A1 contains the link https://www.website.com/content/12345.

Then I know I can make a new column alongside Column A and type this formula into B1: `=HYPERLINK(A1,"here")`. Then cell B1 will contain the text link `here` and it'll go to https://www.website.com/content/12345.

However, I want to delete Column A after I have the neat Column B. Or say I want to copy the neat Column B into another spreadsheet. If I do either of those, the links in Column B stop working. I've tried pasting as values, but all that does is make each cell read `here` with no link. So I need to take every cell reference in the `HYPERLINK` function and convert it to the text in the cell it refers to. For example, I need to run a function that takes the formula `=HYPERLINK(A1,"here")` and turns it into `=HYPERLINK(https://www.website.com/content/12345,"here")`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two macro proposals to get the job done:

```
Sub ReplaceRef()
    Dim rng As Range, prec As Range
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each rng In Selection
        On Error Resume Next
        Set prec = rng.DirectPrecedents
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not prec Is Nothing Then
            rng.Formula = Replace(rng.Formula, prec.Address(0, 0), _
                """" & prec.Value & """")
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub AddHyperFun()
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Next.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & rng.Value & """,""here"")"
    Next rng
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

In the first macro you should select cells with HYPERLINK functions in column B. Then the macro will replace references to column A by their values.

For the second macro you should select links in column A. Macro will add HYPERLINK functions and place results in column B (next to Selection).